# Replace an entry in data frame by the number of the column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find entries in an R dataframe based on their value in order to be able to replace them by the number of the column each of these entries is located in. Well, it's easy to modify particular entries based on their location or based on their value. Let's say this would replace all zeros in the data frame with 1:

```
df[df==0]<-1
```

But how do you replace all zeros in your df by the number of the column they're in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[df==0] <- which(df==0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[]<-lapply(1:ncol(df),function(i){
 ifelse(df[,i]!=0,df[,i],i)
})
```